# Gracefully handling errors when parsing dates in DuckDB

Tags: duckdb

While ingesting some very poor quality data I'd like to use `strptime` and nullify any entries that error on strptime.

I can manually specify exclusions with a case statement:

```sql
select * EXCLUDE (date_of_birth),
CASE
   WHEN date_of_birth[5:6]::int <= 12 AND 
        date_of_birth[5:6]::int > 0 AND
        date_of_birth[7:]::int <= 31 AND
        NOT (date_of_birth[5:6]::int = 11 AND date_of_birth[7:]::int >= 31) AND
        NOT (date_of_birth[5:6]::int = 2 AND date_of_birth[7:]::int >= 29)
   THEN strptime(date_of_birth, '%Y%m%d')::DATE
   ELSE NULL
END AS date_of_birth

from read_csv_auto(
    'bad_data.csv', 
    types={'date_of_birth': 'VARCHAR'}
)
```

But this method is very unsatisfactory. For one I can't anticipate all possible bad dates - and in this instance I'm not able to change the source system. Can anyone point me in a better direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to filter e.g.,

```sql
select * EXCLUDE (date_of_birth),
CASE
   WHEN regexp_matches(date_of_birth, '^[12]\d{3}[01]\d[0-3]\d$')
   THEN strptime(date_of_birth, '%Y%m%d')::DATE
   ELSE NULL
END AS date_of_birth
```

Or a more complex one if that still fails.

Comment: Thanks, using regex to pre-validate is very similar to what I'm doing - certainly more powerful! But it still has the issue that a user has to to define the ruls (regex or otherwise) for all valid dates instead of being able to somehow catch the `Conversion Error` that `strptime` produces.

Comment: We have a new function `try_strptime` in test that will return `NULL` instead of throwing. It can also take a list of formats, as well as just a single one. `strptime` is also being extended to take a list, but it will fail if none of them work.